# Nodejs - Worker accepting new request even after cluster.worker.disconnect() is called

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to close the nodejs worker after `'x' seconds` and when I am trying to close the worker after specified time interval by calling `cluster.worker.disconnect()`, the same worker is still accepting new requests before processexit() is called and worker is not restarting gracefully.

**Need help to identify how to stop the server from receiving further requests after 'x' seconds and process the existing request and restart gracefully.**

Currently, I am thinking of this approach, this approach won't restart the server exactly after 'x' seconds but it will eventually restart gracefully.

1) After 'x seconds' call the below snippet

```
if (cluster.worker) {
    cluster.worker.disconnect();
}
server.close();
```

2) Then handle the close event of server and server will trigger close when it is idle and will close the server.

```
server.on('close', function(){
    console.log("Closed the server worker with pid: " + process.pid + " port: " + process.env.PORT + " date: " + staticFunctions.getLogDate());
    if(cluster.worker){
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```

3) Then use the exit event handler of the process to fork new worker:

```
cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log("worker => exit with pid: "+ worker.process.pid+" Died. Restarting. port: " + process.env.PORT + " date: " + staticFunctions.getLogDate());
    var id = some_id;
    setTimeout(function() {
       var worker = cluster.fork({'workerId' : id});
    },2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the server.close which the node guys are not read yto accept.

You can follow the issue on GitHub
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2642#issuecomment-229753639